# How can I have a button run an Applescript?

Tags: xcode, button, interface-builder, terminal, applescript

I am using Xcode and Interface Builder. My Xcode project is based off the Applescript template. I have a button in interface builder. I want

```
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "list" in front window
    end tell
```

to run when the button is clicked. Btw it's Xcode 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need some basic tutorials to learn this. It's not something that can be explained easily. I found one [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30274) but you should search there because I know there's more tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks like a really good starting point.